# Flutter web app does not opening at firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am making so simple web app with Flutter. But I does not opened on Firebase Hosting. I tried to change the index.html. And I changed the path of my index folder. It gives me some errors such as _flutter is not defined. I clean it. But this time it gives me a different error message. How can I publish my web site smoothly?

Here is the link:

https://triyingweb.web.app/

index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="./">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="sdk_flutter_2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>sdk_flutter_2</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="/main.dart.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1113.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('sw-cached-site.js', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {
        scope: '/',
      });
    });
  }
  window.process = { env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' } };
  </script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>


</body>
<script>
  <script>
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCYgkDBNvQukJaCvit3lH8vpY8ISi1ld7I",
  authDomain: "triyingweb.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "triyingweb",
  storageBucket: "triyingweb.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "778280603165",
  appId: "1:778280603165:web:f7752b68d3d4b7348440f4",
  measurementId: "G-5D0GNTWXBS"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

</script>





</html>
```

Firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```